# Loading javascript from server

Tags: javascript

we develop a cloud software and we have the problem with loading javascript in Chrome. We change a javascript file on our server, but some users' chrome does not load this and keeps working with an old version that is not compatible.

I am not able to explain 1.000 users how they can delete cache. CTRL+F5 does not work. What can I set to tell Chrome: "Hey, there is a new version!"? Any help?

We compile assets (javascript).

Comment: For example `<script src="/static/v1.2/scripts/script.js"></script>`